# how to install openssh 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10

Tags: 14.04, openssh

I have downloaded the openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10.debian.tar.gz from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10,

Need help in installing it on the server.

Comment: What was wrong with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`? If you need to get it offline, then you can get it [from packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&section=all&arch=any&keywords=openssh&searchon=names) ...

Comment: @N0rbert It installs `openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.11`, i want to downgrade to `openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10`

Comment: Did you [read changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.11/changelog) of the package? Why are you trying to install insecure version?

Comment: Yes i did, this change is temporary. trying to fix some version dependency issues in my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to install this **insecure version**, then you should visit [aforementioned page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.10) and click on one of builds links:

> [image: builds]

then select architecture and download corresponding deb-packages.